# Integral of line and Green.

Tags: calculus

$\int_{C} xydx + x^2dy$, where C is the rectangle with vertices $(0,0),(3,0),(3,1),(0,1)$.

I don't understand why the result does not agree with the predict by Green theorem:
The rectangle has four regions, two lines parallel to x, and so is to y.

The first line $(0,0);(3,0)$ the integral is zero, since $y = dy = 0$

The second line $(3,0);(3,1)$ is $\int 9 \space dy = 9$

The third line $(3,1);(0,1)$ is $\int x \space dx = 0-9^2/2$

The fourth line $(0,1);(0,0)$ is zero

So the results is $9-9²/2$

Now, the green theorem: $\int (2x-x)dxdy = 9^2/2$

?? This is different from the predict!

Comment: Why is $\int x dx = -9^{2}/2$? Shouldn't it be $-9/2$?

Comment: You have mistake in the integral over second line segment. It should be $-9/2$. Then you have mistake in working using Green's theorem. It returns $9/2$ so they do match.